# DateTimeFormatter to parse all ISO-valid styles of zone-offset

Tags: java, java-time

With the following formatter I'm able to parse `"2017-03-28T23:40:06.000+0100"`

```
new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
            .append(ISO_LOCAL_DATE_TIME)
            .appendPattern("X")
            .toFormatter();
```

With another one it parses `"2017-03-28T23:40:06.000+01:00"`

```
new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
            .append(ISO_LOCAL_DATE_TIME)
            .appendPattern("XX")
            .toFormatter();
```

However, I'm unable to specify formatter that parses both. What pattern should I append?

Formatter should also be able to process timestamps without zone-offset, e.g. `"2017-03-28T23:40:06.000Z"`

Answer (score 1):

Since the [DateTimeFormatterBuilder](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatterBuilder.html) behaves like a fluent interface, the easiest way is to append both of the patterns:

```
new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
        .append(ISO_LOCAL_DATE_TIME)
        .appendPattern("X")
        .appendPattern("XX")
        .toFormatter();
```

Comment: With that I cannot parse another format: `java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '2017-03-28T23:40:06.000Z' could not be parsed, unparsed text found at index 23

Comment: Surprisingly, Joda seems cannot work like this :/

Answer (score 1):

The following started to work for me

```
new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
            .append(ISO_LOCAL_DATE_TIME)
            .optionalStart()
            .appendPattern("[XXX][X]")
            .toFormatter();
```

Answer (score 0):

I once had a task to parse any String to Date if the String represent a valid Date not knowing format in advance. Basically I needed to format String of any possible format. I came up with an idea where you write into a file all data formats that you wish to support and then read the formats one by one and try to parse a String by that format until you succeed or run out of formats. Here is the link to the article that describe the idea in more detail: [Java 8 java.time package: parsing any string to date](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/java-8-javatime-package-parsing-any-string-date-michael-gantman/)

Comment: I know format in advance, it must be ISO-valid format

Comment: Yes, I understand that you know in advance some limitations of your formats, but you can not create a single format that covers all possible options. Therefore you can apply the same idea as I suggested. Have several formats that together cover all valid options and try to parse your String with those formats one by one

Comment: That's exactly what I did, thanks. See my answer.